# How to cross check between multiple python lists in order to find duplicate IDs

Tags: python, list

I have three lists that have request IDs for emails, titles and text in that emails. I'm trying to compare email title and text and if those are duplicated then get IDs for them. Lists are ordered in a way that `id1` has `'title1'` and `'sampleText1'`, `id3` has `'title2'` and `'sampleText2'` etc:

```
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
title = ['title1', 'title1', 'title2' 'title3', 'title3', 'title4']
text = ['sampleText1', 'sampleText1' 'sampleText2', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText4]
```

from the above lists I have to establish which ones are duplicates and my desired output for the above would be:

```
 id = [2, 5]
```

Would someone be able to help with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean to say if `title1` = `sampleText1` than give `1`?

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you fix it

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can do with for loop like this:

```
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
title = ['title1', 'title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title3', 'title4']
text = ['sampleText1', 'sampleText1', 'sampleText2', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText4']

result = []

for x in id:
    tmptitle = title[x-1]
    tmptext = text[x-1]
    if x > 0:
        if tmptitle == title[x-2] and tmptext == text[x-2]:
            result.append(x)

print(result)
```

for another question please provide your code that you wrote to solve your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the list sizes are same.  All you need to do is iterate over 'title' and compare (nested loops) elements at each index. Code below

```
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
title = ['title1', 'title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title3', 'title4']
text = ['sampleText1', 'sampleText1', 'sampleText2', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText4']
res = []
for i in range(len(id)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(id)): #i+1 'cause we need to start comparing from the next index
        if title[i] == title[j]:
            res.append(id[j])
            break

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would the one below in which the order of `title` and `text` does not matter:

```
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
title = ['title1', 'title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title3', 'title4']
text = ['sampleText1', 'sampleText1', 'sampleText2', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText3', 'sampleText4']


dupTitles = [] # Titles that are already checked.
dupTexts = [] # Texts that are already checked.
result = [] # Final list of IDs.

for elemId, elemTitle, elemText in zip(id,title,text):
    if elemTitle in dupTitles and elemText in dupTexts:
        result.append(elemId)
    else:
        dupTitles.append(elemTitle)
        dupTexts.append(elemText)

print(result)
```

The result will be:

```
[2, 5]
```